# Explain this bad parking job

Tags: situation, real

One bright Monday morning, I drove to work and parked my car in Lot A. That morning, others also parked in Lot A, and we all found each other’s parking jobs to be satisfactory.

That afternoon, a co-worker, who was a nervous driver, and who was my neighbor at home, asked me to ride with her to provide moral support. She was parked in Lot B, and we rode in her car.

The next morning, Tuesday, she drove me back to work, and she parked in Lot B as usual. That Tuesday afternoon, I walked to Lot A and was quite embarrassed to see that my car was parked across four different parking spots, and crooked, exactly where I had parked it in on Monday morning. How did this happen?

[image: Bad parking job]

Comment: The average BMW owner does that all the time, so there's no need to be embarrassed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A possibility is that on Monday your parking lot was

> covered in snow. Cars were parked aligned with each other, but not exactly with the painted parking lines. The snow may also explain why your co-worker was concerned. Then, after the other cars in Lot A left later on Monday, the snow was cleared, leaving your car out of position, and the new arrivals on Tue parked in the painted spaces.

Comment: By 30 seconds @Tom?

Comment: @DrD, sno' difference -  I like that you experienced this.

Comment: I also experienced not finding my car because it snowed 2 feet one time and all cars were "snowed under"

Comment: My first thought was "snow", but I kept reading "Lot A" as "LA", and it don't generally snow in LA...

Comment: @DrD You haven't experienced true hatred for snow until you've spent 15 minutes digging out *the wrong car*.  (Due to the practice at my old school of plowing one end of the parking lot, then towing all the cars to the other end to plow the other side, and towing them back, but in a different order, so your car was never where you left it.)

Comment: This is a new one @DarrelHoffman. Heard stories of cars on upstate NY streets snowed in for weeks. Mine is not as sad as yours. But I had my Garbage cans on the curb under the snow for the month of January. Long story.

Answer (score 11):

This happened to me in a commuter parking lot in New England in January.

> When you parked either it was snowing or some snow on the ground. Everyone parked as they saw fit but not knowing where the actual spaces were. You parked parallel to the other cars. Next day the snow had been melted (or the lot was cleaned nicely) so everyone knew where to park!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps,

> You parked the car correctly but the lot got repainted and since you were the only one not driving back in your car, it got misplaced.

Comment: Welcome to SE Puzzling @Pangolin. Do you think they would paint AROUND the car and leave portions under the car unpainted?